# Adding multiple items per single listing

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to be able to add multiple items per listing (like eBay variation drop down menu). I'm going to being to start selling Mobile Handsets and Covers and want to have the one listing with multiple variations of colours.

I've had a look around the Magento Marketplace for something but cannot find anything I'm looking for. Do you guys know of any addons that have the ability to do this?

Thanks, Steve

Comment: Are you referring to adding items with colour? Have a look magento config listing.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.
For anyone else having difficulty, Create a Product with "Configurable Product" and have the selection you want to "Global" in your Manage Attributes.